# strings and prints them as columns from list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have list of lists of strings like this:

```
[['today'], ['is'], ['rainy'], ['day']]
```

I want to print each word vertically in python. I want to output something like this

```
t i r d
o s a a
d   i y
a   n  
y   y
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Ideally you want to show the code of your attempt implementing the algorithm, where and why you think it fails, etc.

Comment: Is the list over each string intentional?.  you have a list of list, where each list contains a string

Comment: yes I have a list of lists of strings contain a string, but it can be converted back to a normal list of string @RishabhKumar

Answer (score 3):

You could try `itertools.zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest
lst = [['today'], ['is'], ['rainy'], ['day']]
print('\n'.join([' '.join([y or ' ' for y in x]) for x in zip_longest(*[i[0] for i in lst])]))
```

Output:

```
t i r d
o s a a
d   i y
a   n  
y   y
```

Comment: In this case I'd use `y or ' '` instead of `' ' if y is None else y`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this will a loop.

```
l =  [['today'], ['is'], ['rainy'], ['day']]

max_len = len(max(l, key=lambda x: len(x[0]))[0])
out = ''

for idx in range(max_len):
    for item in l:
        small_item = item[0]
        if len(small_item) > idx:
            out += small_item[idx]
            out += "\t"
        else:
            out += " \t"
    out += "\n"

print(out)

t   i   r   d   
o   s   a   a   
d       i   y   
a       n       
y       y
```

Idea behind this is simple. You have to find the length of longest string you have. Then basically you want to pick up each item from each string if that element is valid, else add a empty space. Add tabs and newlines to format as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [['today'], ['is'], ['rainy'], ['day']]
max_len = len(max(lst, key=lambda x: len(x[0]))[0])

for i in range(max_len):
    for word in lst:
        try:
            print(word[0][i], end=' ')
        except IndexError:
            print(' ', end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
t i r d 
o s a a
d   i y
a   n
y   y
```